# Type 'Observable<Product[] | Order>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Product[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript

This comes from the book "Pro_Angular", chapter 8.

```
getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get, "products");
}

saveOrder(order: Order) : Observable<Order> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Post, "orders", order);
}

private sendRequest(verb: RequestMethod,
   url: string, body?: Product | Order): Observable<Product[] | Order> {
       return this.http.request(new Request({
           method: verb,
           url: this.baseUrl + url,
           body: body
       })).map(response => response.json())
}
```

The warning message is:

```
[ts]Type 'Observable<Product[] | Order>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Product[]>'.
Type 'Product[] | Order' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
Type 'Order' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
Property 'length' is missing in type 'Order'.
```

and:

```
[ts]Type 'Observable<Product[] | Order>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Order>'.
Type 'Product[] | Order' is not assignable to type 'Order'.
Type 'Product[]' is not assignable to type 'Order'.
Property 'id' is missing in type 'Product[]'.
```

It seems this issue is caused by the OR (`|`) operator. I am wondering how to make the body of `sendRequest()` take multiple parameters (here either `Product` or `Order`).

Comment: Why are you trying to narrow everything through a single method to send a request? That makes it *much* harder to provide type safety unless you use generic types; what can you reasonably do with an observable of "anything my backend could possibly return, who knows"? Actually *use* the HttpClient generic type handling, make a separate request in each of the two other methods and delete the third entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the variable to a type of:

`Observable<Product[]> | Observable<Order>` ?

I believe it is looking for a type of `Product[] | Order` which i am not sure if that is a valid type.